# TabHost inside fragment in HoenyComb

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, fragment

I have started currently an portfolio application for HoneyComb tablet. I have used ActionBar.Tab to implement three tab on the ActionBar and Fragment for each Tab. The three tab name About, Gallery, Settings. In the Settings ActionBar.Tab, I want to have TabHost.
That means How to have TabHost inside Fragment. Thanks in advance for your ideas!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a layout with a tabhost like (assuming you define this as my_fragment_tabhost):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

In your fragment, have a TabHost member variable and get it in the onCreateView like:

```
    private TabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment_tabhost, container, false);
        mTabHost = (TabHost) view.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();//very important to call this

        TabHost.TabSpec tab = mTabHost.newTabSpec("my tab content");
        tab.setIndicator("my tab content")
//... add your content by one of the tab.setContent() methods
        mTabHost.addTab(tab);
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: You just saved my ass with this mTabHost.setup(); Thank you.